# Why will this query run in MySQL 5 but not in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql

We are in the process of migrating from MySQL 5 to 8 and I found a query that will work in 5 but not 8.

Senario: I'm trying to find records that have been flagged as not having breast screening related data, but actually do have this data in the system.  My main record is a Cycle record (t_cycle table).  Each of the other related records have a link to the cycle table.  In this simplified version of the query I'm looking for cycles that do not have a mammogram record but do have either an office visit or an MRI. But I'm only interested if the office visit had a procedure done with a specific result.  I'm getting the list of acceptable results by querying another result table. In the actual query I have multiple other tables joined in but this demonstrates the problem.

Here is the query that works in 5 but not version 8:

```sql
SELECT 
               cyc.f_enroll_id,
               cyc.f_cycle_number,
               ov.f_cbe_result,
               mri.f_uid as 'MRI'
FROM
               t_cycle cyc LEFT JOIN
               t_mam_rpt mam ON cyc.f_uid = mam.f_cycle_uid LEFT JOIN
               t_office_visit ov ON cyc.f_uid = ov.f_cycle_uid AND ov.f_cbe_result IN (SELECT f_code FROM t_lk_cbe_result WHERE f_mde_code IN (1,2)) LEFT JOIN 
               t_mri mri ON cyc.f_uid = mri.f_cycle_uid 
WHERE
               cyc.f_mam_indication = 5 AND
               mam.f_uid IS NULL AND
               (ov.f_uid IS NOT NULL OR
               mri.f_uid IS NOT NULL);
```

In version 5 I get about 20 records back.  In version 8 I get over 7000 and most of those have office visits where the CBE result is not in the list of acceptable results.

There are 2 variations that appear to work in 8:

```sql
/* appears to work (removed the OR mri.f_uid IS NOT NULL) */
SELECT 
               cyc.f_enroll_id,
               cyc.f_cycle_number,
               ov.f_cbe_result,
               mri.f_uid as 'MRI'
FROM
               t_cycle cyc LEFT JOIN
               t_mam_rpt mam ON cyc.f_uid = mam.f_cycle_uid LEFT JOIN
               t_office_visit ov ON cyc.f_uid = ov.f_cycle_uid AND ov.f_cbe_result IN (SELECT f_code FROM t_lk_cbe_result WHERE f_mde_code IN (1,2)) LEFT JOIN 
               t_mri mri ON cyc.f_uid = mri.f_cycle_uid 
WHERE
               cyc.f_mam_indication = 5 AND
               mam.f_uid IS NULL AND
              ov.f_uid IS NOT NULL ;
```

In the above version I modify the WHERE clause to not have the 'OR mri.f_uid IS NOT NULL)' but in the actual use, this is not an option.

This also seems to work:

```sql
/* appears to work - replaced the SELECT in the JOIN with hard coded values that are returned in the select) */
SELECT 
               cyc.f_enroll_id,
               cyc.f_cycle_number,
               ov.f_cbe_result,
               mri.f_uid as 'MRI'
FROM
               t_cycle cyc LEFT JOIN
               t_mam_rpt mam ON cyc.f_uid = mam.f_cycle_uid LEFT JOIN
               t_office_visit ov ON cyc.f_uid = ov.f_cycle_uid AND ov.f_cbe_result IN (2,30,31,33,34,35,38,39,40,42,43,44,45,46,47) LEFT JOIN 
               t_mri mri ON cyc.f_uid = mri.f_cycle_uid 
WHERE
               cyc.f_mam_indication = 5 AND
               mam.f_uid IS NULL AND
               (ov.f_uid IS NOT NULL OR
               mri.f_uid IS NOT NULL);
```

In the above case I replaced by sub-SELECT in the office visit join with a list of acceptable results.  In reality, I cannot do this because that list is going to vary.

I guess my question boils down to why are office visit records being included in the result set even when they don't have the correct result code?

I don't post often here, so hopefully I've provided enough information.

TIA for any help!
-Carolyn

Additional Information: 8/4/21
I tried to get a small subset of data to recreate the problem but it only seems to show up with a large set of data in the office visit table (the one that has the join that includes a subquery).

If I remove the subquery from the join and instead left join my list of codes and then adjust the WHERE clause to do the check there, it works correctly.  This is what the modified code looks like:

```sql
SELECT 
   cyc.f_enroll_id,
   cyc.f_cycle_number,
   ov.f_cbe_result,
   mri.f_uid as 'MRI'
FROM
   t_cycle cyc LEFT JOIN
   t_office_visit ov ON cyc.f_uid = ov.f_cycle_uid LEFT JOIN
   t_lk_cbe_result lk ON ov.f_cbe_result = lk.f_code LEFT JOIN 
   t_mam_rpt mam ON cyc.f_uid = mam.f_cycle_uid LEFT JOIN
   t_mri mri ON cyc.f_uid = mri.f_cycle_uid 
WHERE
   cyc.f_mam_indication = 5 AND
   mam.f_uid IS NULL AND 
   ((ov.f_uid IS NOT NULL AND lk.f_mde_code IN (1,2)) OR
   mri.f_uid IS NOT NULL)
```

We are using version 8.0.18 so it could very likely be a bug that has already been fixed as mentioned in the comments.  We are going to upgrade again and see if that takes care of it.  Thanks to all who looked at this and feel free to continue to reply if you know this had been a known issue.  If there is a place to find known issues with mySQL I'd appreciate that link as well.

Comment: Compare table structures and then contents between v8 and v5 probably during the backup and transfer some null data  was transformed to null/empty, especially `t_mri` and `t_office_visit`

Comment: Structures are the same, and I'm not seeing any null data in the linking fields.

Comment: >> Senario: I'm trying to find records that have been flagged as not having breast screening related data, but actually do have this data in the system.  -- It's best to show the real SQL.  Define your business terms relative to your tables / columns.  What is "flagged as not having breast screening" and "but actually do have this data in the system".  This should be a trivial query.  Note: It's also best to provide test data / inserts, create table statements and the exact result you expect, given that data.

Comment: If the f_mam_indication field in the t_cycle table has a value of 5, that means it is not a breast screening cycle.  But breast screening data is entered in mammogram (t_mam_rpt), Office visit (t_office_visit), and MRI (t_mri) tables.  So I LEFT JOIN to those and look to see if there are any of those records linked to the cycle.  If there are, the results should include that information.  I can pull a sample of data and give you the create/insert statements but that will take a bit to pull out.

Comment: Can you specify your mysql version and/or can you test this on a recent version? There have been some optimizer bugs with nested subqueries, maybe it's one of them.

Comment: The only data you need to provide is just enough to show a single result row (or missing result row) you believe is wrong in either database (5 or 8).  The create table statements, the insert statements and the exact SQL that does not produce the result you expect.

Comment: We are using version 8.0.18.  I'll work on pulling together a sample probably tonight or tomorrow.